# how to set global variables and access them from chrome console in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

assigning variables to `window` does not work. Is there another way? This is just for testing purposes. For example, I'd like to access the Performance tools from the console simply like this:

```
Perf.start()
Pert.stop()
```

Comment: It looks like at the moment we can only add `debugger` into our code and use chrome dev tools to play with the code. Source: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html

Comment: actually u just need to be in the debugger frame and the above does work as i learned.